# What happens when CreateWaitableTimer is set for non-existing date/time?

Tags: c++, winapi, timer, dst

The Daylight Saving Time (United States) in 2013 began at 2:00 AM on Sunday, March 10. So, say, now is March 9, 2013 and I call the following API on an already created waitable timer handle:

```
FILETIME ftWhen = //Points as absolute time to March 10th, 2013, at 2:10 AM
SetWaitableTimer(hTimer, ftWhen, 0, NULL, NULL, TRUE);
```

`March 10th, 2013, 2:10 AM` is a non-existent time because the time will be adjusted one hour ahead so instead of 2 AM it will be 3 AM.

So my question, what will happen to my timer? (I can't seem to find documentation for this case.)

Comment: Why don't create such a Situation by simply forwarding your internal clock for a few minutes?

Comment: +1. But people don't tend to foresee so far ahead )

Comment: Yeah, I'm playing with it now but I get "weird effects" in OS and Visual Studio. I thought to find some official documentation for this...

Comment: I am getting similar "weird effects" on my smartphone every year when time changes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suspect you already know the answer to your question, because your comment explicitly states:

```
// Points _as absolute time_ to March 10th, 2013, at 2:10 AM
```

So you're aware that the documentation for [SetWaitableTimer()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686289.aspx) says:

> Be sure to use a UTC-based absolute time, as the system uses UTC-based
>   time internally.

Since UTC does not care about DST whatsoever, your timer will be triggered on `March 10th, 2013, 3:10 AM`, *your local time*.

Comment: Hmm. Good point. Yeah, I missed that UTC part. It makes sense now. Thanks for pointing it out...

Comment: Taking into account all this time related mess we inherit, this is still a very good question to ask.

Answer (score 3):

`SetWaitableTimer` expects the `pDueTime` to be given in UTC; so there's no way to call it with such a non-existing date/time.